# Reading Turkish characters from CSV file in Python 3.8

Tags: python, csv

I wanted to write a simple dictionary program for myself, store the unknown english words and meanings in a csv file, and everytime I run the  program, it shuffles all words in english and have me to input correct turkish translation. I've tried to read my csv file for testing and it didn't recognised the turkish characters. (as seen below) I've added the *encoding='utf-8'* parameter in *open()* function. What should I do?

I can try other solutions than reading it from a csv file, I'm new to python and only know few about reading files.

the code:

```
import csv
english_words = []
turkish_words = []

with open('all_words.csv' , encoding='utf-8') as words_csv:
    words = csv.DictReader(words_csv)
    for row in words:
        english_words.append(row['english'])
        turkish_words.append(row['turkish'])

print(english_words)
print(turkish_words)
```

Output:

```
['immersion', 'brow', 'intact', 'snort', 'demented', 'supper', 'envy', 'unconventional', 'improvise', 'indulge', 'slumber', 'itenarary', 'occasional', 'aberrant', 'grotesque', 'mettle', 'rind', 'inconsistencies', 'repetitions', 'cease', 'errands', 'pluck', 'cruel', 'reveries', 'decommission', 'mischief']
['dald²rma', 'ka■', 'bozulmam²■', 'homurdanma', 'Bunak', 'ak■am yeme­i', 'imrenme', 'al²■²lmad²k', 'do­alama', '■²martmak', 'uyuklama', 'yol k²lavuzu', 'nadiren', 'anormal', 'grotesk', '■evk', 'd²■ y³zey', 'tutars²zl²klar ', 'tekrarlar²', 'durdurmak', 'ayak i■leri', 'yolmak', 'zalim', 'h³lyalar', 'faaliyetine son', 'yarmazl²k']
```

An example of my csv file :

```
english,turkish
immersion,daldırma
brow,kaş
intact,bozulmamış
snort,homurdanma
demented,Bunak
supper,akşam yemeği
envy,imrenme
unconventional,alışılmadık
improvise,doğaçlama
indulge,şımartmak
slumber,uyuklama
itenarary,yol kılavuzu
occasional,nadiren
aberrant,anormal
grotesque,grotesk
mettle,şevk
rind,dış yüzey
inconsistencies,tutarsızlıklar 
repetitions,tekrarları
cease,durdurmak
errands,ayak işleri
pluck,yolmak
cruel,zalim
reveries,hülyalar
decommission,faaliyetine son
mischief,yarmazlık
```

Comment: My guess would be your input file is not in UTF-8 encoding…

Comment: Tried to change it in excel, saved as a UTF-8 csv file, now I get a KeyError while trying to read.

Comment: Show a sample of your CSV (after conversion to UTF-8), please. Add it to the question.

Comment: Did what you've said @Błotosmętek

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it: your CSV file is UTF-8 **with BOM**; Python uses `utf-8-sig` name for this. Just change `encoding='utf-8'` to `encoding='utf-8-sig'` and it should work.

Comment: Tried it, didn't worked. Saved the csv file in all diffrent formats in excel, got the same result again.

Comment: "Same result" ie. `KeyError`? if so, comment out the two lines with `append` and put `print(row)` there instead; see what is printed.